# How to add Preemptible GPU and SSDs to GCloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

When creating a instance using google compute engine if I select availability policy as Preemptibility to On, does that instance uses Preemptible GPUs and SSDs ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, yes. [Local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemptible_with_local_ssd) & [GPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible#preemptible_with_gpu) attached to preemptible instances work like normal GPUs but persist only for the life of the instance.

You will be charged for SSDs & GPUs at a [preemptible price](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing), and they will use your regular SSD or GPU quota, [unless you request one only for that](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#quotas_for_preemptible_resources).

Comment: Is there any log or something to view whether the instance used preemptible GPU and SSD ?